# Countable orthonormal basis of product of separable Hilbert spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces

If I have 2 separable Hilbert spaces $X$ and $Y$ which have (different) orthonormal bases $x_i$ and $y_i$, then clearly $x_i \times y_j$ is a basis for $X \times Y$ (which is also a separable space).

But it is not orthonormal. Do I have to use a Gram-Schmidt thing or is there a nice way of renorming or something to make it orthonormal? I mean, is there a nice formula?

I gave the product space the inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)_X + (\cdot,\cdot)_Y$.

Comment: $\{x_i\times y_j\}$ is not a basis. Try $\{x_i\times 0\}\cup\{0\times y_j\}$

Comment: By saying "product", do you mean [direct sum or tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Constructions)?

Comment: @Landscape I mean the direct sum.

Comment: @Diego Well it's dense, I believe..

Comment: Then following the notations in the wikipedia page, an orthonormal  basis of $X\oplus Y$ should be $\{(x_i,0),(0,y_j):\forall i,j\}$, which is essentially what @Diego means.

Comment: @Landscape Unless I'm very confused, $((x_i,0),(0,y_j))_{X \times Y} = 0$ even when $i=j$. How can this be?

Comment: Your equation means the two vectors on the left hand side are othorgonal, which is compatible with the definition of orthonormal basis. What confuses you?

Comment: I suggest you should recall the definition of orthonormal basis.

Comment: Even when $i = j$, you're still dotting two different, orthogonal vectors. However, if you do $\langle (x_i, 0), (x_i, 0) \rangle$ then you get something nonzero.

Comment: Oh yes, that's right, thanks, got confused @ChristopherA.Wong

Comment: @Landscape Thanks I got it.

Comment: You are welcome. You may post an answer by yourself.